# iOS cracking scripts

Tags: jailbreak, ios, cydia

I am jailbroken running iOS 8.1 and was wondering if there are any working app cracking scripts similar to clutch or rasticrac. So far, the ones I have tried do not fully work on iOS 8.1. I do have experience so I do not mind advanced methods. I also do not want an illegal App Store that allows you to download IPAs. Also, are there any free tools for Macs that I could use? Thank you

Edit:
I am not going to use this for piracy

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using it for piracy (I assume you're maybe trying to access class method names to make a jailbreak tweak?) use [dumpdecrypted](https://github.com/stefanesser/dumpdecrypted).

It allows you to decrypt a code-signed application, but due to the decryption method it wont allow the binary to run on iOS.

All decryption is handled on the device (you perform it over SSH by copying the dylib and running the binary), which means the app you wish to decrypt must also be installed to your device (or extracted and copied to `/var/mobile/Applications` or wherever iOS 8 changed it to)